# How to use WHEN condition in trigger opertion

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I want to insert the data from Ac_holders to loan when the balance in Ac_holders table less than zero. And like to update the negative value as positive and insert into the amount in the loan table. 
And thank you in advance.

````
mysql> create trigger Triggeroverdraft after insert on Ac_holders
   -> for each row when balance<0
   -> begin
   ->  insert into loan(id, name,amonut) values (new.id, new.name, new.amount);
   -> end```
````

Answer (score 0):

Formally:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Triggeroverdraft 
AFTER INSERT 
ON Ac_holders
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO loan(id, name, amount) 
    SELECT new.id, new.name, new.amount
    WHERE ???.balance < 0;              -- NEW.balance ?
```